# Is it possible to authenticate https://ghcr.io for ECS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, ghcr

I have ECS service, which needs to pull image from https://ghcr.io via PAT token.
Is this possible at all? Is there any way to authenticate to github container registry?

Thank you for the assistance!

BR,

Martin

Comment: check this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/containers/authenticating-with-docker-hub-for-aws-container-services/). I pretty sure that `ghcr.io` authentication process is the same as `docker hub`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's possible. The [article](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/containers/authenticating-with-docker-hub-for-aws-container-services/) linked in the comment to the question shows how it is done, as does the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html).

The article covers everything you need to do, at a high level:

- Create a PAT token for a Github user that has at least 'read' access to the required repo.
- Create an AWS SecretsManager secret containing credentials, in format `{ "username":"<gh-username>", "password":"<PAT-token>" }`
- Grant the TaskExecutionRole (*not TaskRole*) access to this secret - it's the execution role that requires access to pull the image.
- Set the `repository_credentials` property of the container definition to the arn of the secret containing credentials